# Reference a user's username in a SiteMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, sitemap

I'm working in MVC 3 with C#. I'm working on security trimming. I'm obviously implementing it through a sitemap. My question is can I pass the user's current user name to the sitemap? My goal is to have an "account" link that has text equal to the user's user name. Right now my sitemap code looks like:

`<siteMapNode title="Account" description="Account settings" url="~/Account" />`

This code is nestled correctly and everything is fine. I just want to know how to make the title section update dynamically and match the user's username. Is this possible?

Additional information: all trimming is done through the code expressed in [this](http://joyofexcellence.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/16/security-trimming-for-mvc-menus/) article. Additionally, this is my sitemap string:

`<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >`

Profiles are done through ASP .NET SQL Profile/Role Provider. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpContext.Current.User if not null

Comment: That works in C#. It doesn't do anything in the .sitemap file though. Putting it in without quotes throws an error (unsurprisingly) and tossing it in single or double quotes has it render as is. Sorry, I shouldn't have tossed the C# tag in the question, I removed it though.

Comment: I was suggesting modifying your sitemap provider to make use of the HTTPContext.Current.User while it builds your site map for the user.

Comment: Oh ok, I've never modified my sitemap provider before, so I wasn't sure where you wanted me to use that bit of code =X. I assumed in the .sitemap file. I'll look that up. Thanks for the tip.